# Is it possible to order JSON object of Key Value Pairs when keys change and values are more key value pairs.

Tags: python, json, string, sorting

In python, I'm having trouble figuring out how to output the JSON object (expressed below) as a string wherein the contents of Baseball are ordered based on "key1" (descending). When I receive the JSON (from the datasources) it's got the players out of order. Ultimately, my code needs to order the players, and then pass it along to the next function ordered. Please assume that I cannot modify the format of the JSON to be/have arrays as the consuming function can't handle that (as it's currently written).

Example JSON:

```
 {
    "DataSource1":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Sean":{
                "key1":"10",
            },
            "Gene":{
               "key1":"100",
            },
            "Alan":{
                "key1":"1",
            }
        }
    },
    "DataSource2":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Bob_Smith":{
                "key1":"1"
            },
            "Adam_Filmore":{
               "key1":"100"
            },
            "Joe_Allen":{
                "key1":"10"
            }
        }
    }
    "DataSource3":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Jake":{
                "key1":"10"
            },
            "Huck":{
                "key1":"1"
            },
            "Eric":{
               "key1":"100"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of how I would like JSON to output:

```
 {
    "DataSource1":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Alan":{
                "key1":"1",
            },
            "Sean":{
                "key1":"10",
            },
            "Gene":{
               "key1":"100",
           }
        }
    },
    "DataSource2":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Bob_Smith":{
                "key1":"1"
            },
            "Joe_Allen":{
                "key1":"10"
            },
            "Adam_Filmore":{
               "key1":"100"
            }
        }
    }
    "DataSource3":{
        "Baseball":{
            "Huck":{
                "key1":"1"
            },
            "Jake":{
                "key1":"10"
            },
            "Eric":{
               "key1":"100"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Object properties don't have order in Javascript. You should copy the properties into arrays and then sort that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to establish the sort order you want, then store the results in a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Try this:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for data_source in data:
    data[data_source]["Baseball"] = OrderedDict(
        sorted(data[data_source]["Baseball"].items(),
               key=lambda x: x[1]["key1"]))

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```